# Is there any JavaScript game library good for mobile gaming?

Tags: mobile, browser-based-games

I do not know how should I ask this question. I am a very new in this field. I want to learn game development. I want to learn it for Android and iPhone game development. That's why i was looking for JavaScript game engine or libraries. But, I got many. I do not know which one will good for me for 2D or 3D JavaScript game development.

Comment: Javascript is for browser games, not for phone-specific games, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: That said, there are some very good mobile-specific, JavaScript based game libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://impactjs.com/

Also, check out https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Game-Engines which has a rather good list of JavaScript game development libraries.  It's not just for mobile, but some are mobile.

Plus, consider that you may actually end up combining libraries - one for rendering your game, another (like JQuery Mobile for example) for managing the general mobile device.